# Solve for x in 2^x-5.2^(x+1)=-144 when the x is an exponents applied to different bases?

Tags: exponentiation, integers

**Question:** Find X in 2<sup>x</sup> -5.2<sup>x+1</sup> = -144

**My Attempt to the solution:**

2<sup>x</sup> -5.2<sup>x+1</sup> = -144

2<sup>x</sup>-5.2<sup>x</sup>-5.2<sup>1</sup> = -144

2<sup>x</sup>-5.2<sup>x</sup> = -144 + 5.2

**How would you solve for x when two bases are different?**

**Answer:**

2<sup>x</sup>(1-5.2) = -144

2<sup>x</sup>(-9) = -144

2<sup>x</sup> = 16

**x = 4**

**Also, please tell me what I did wrong in my solution and how where the -9 in the second line under answer came from.**

Comment: About time to read [mathjax references](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553). You might like to refer the second edit before you perform the roll back.

Comment: The second term $5.2^{x+1}$ is probably $5\cdot2^{x+1}$, not $(5.2)^{x+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

You mistake is treating $2^{x+1} = 2^x + 2$ which is not true.

It should be $2^{x+1}=2\cdot 2^x$.

$-9$ comes from $1-2\cdot 5 = 1-10=-9$

Edit:

Further mistake:

Even if you interpret the question as $2^x +(-5.2)^{x+1}=-144$, $$2^x +(-5.2)^{x}(-5.2)=-144$$

This is **not** equivalent to $$2^x-5.2^x-5.2=-144$$

We can't just convert multiplication to addition. '

Remark: If the quesiton is really $$2^x-5.2^x = -144$$

Notice that $2^x-5.2^x$ is a decreasing function for $x>0$, you might want to use bisection method to find the numerical solution.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the solution?  I don't understand where you got the 2^(x+1) and (2)(5) from.

Comment: hmm... $2^{x+1}$ comes from the question. From your first line to the second line, you wrote that $-5\cdot 2^{x+1} = -5 \cdot 2^x -5\cdot 2^1$, this is not true. The $\cdot$ means multiplication. Hence $5\cdot 2 = 10$.

Comment: As inferred from the solution, $\cdot$ means multiplication, it doesn't mean decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

$2^{x+1}=2*2^x $.

So the rest should come naturally.

$2^x-5*2^{x+1}=-144$

$2^x-5*2*2^x=-144$

$2^x-10*2^x=-144$

$2^x (1-10)=-144$

$2^x*(-9)=-144$

$2^x=\frac {-144}{-9}=16$

$2^x=2^4$

$x=4$

And your mistake was thinking $5*2^{x+1}=5*2^x+5*2^1$.  Powers don't distribute over addition.  They distribute over multiplication.  $2^{x+1}\ne 2^x+2^1$.  But $2^{x+1}=2^x*2^1$ instead.